# Vue + Element UI with preview PDF before upload file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, upload, element

I am using Vue and element UI to achieve the upload file function, also use pdfvuer node module.
In this case, the files will upload to Amazon S3 finally.

I want to preview the file before the user click confirms button.
ref picture: [upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJNWc.png)

Currently, I used the blob and createObjectUrl method to realize preview PNG and JPG type files. but not work with PDF type
ref picture: [upload and preview png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E66tn.png)

Here is my code with upload of dialog:

**HTML :**

```
      <span class="pt-0">
        <p class="text-center mt-0">Please selecct file which you want to import</p>
        <el-upload
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf"
          class="avatar-uploader"
          :show-file-list="true"
          :before-upload="beforeAvatarUpload"
          action=""
        >
          <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x my-8" v-if="objectURL == ''"></i>


          <img :src="objectURL" width="100%" />
          <pdf :src="imageUrl.webkitRelativePath" />


          <div class="el-upload__text" v-if="objectURL == ''">Click here to execute</div>
          <div class="el-upload__tip" slot="tip">
            You can just upload PDF/PNG/JPG file only
          </div>
        </el-upload>
      </span>
      <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
        <el-button @click="innerDialogUploadFile = false">Cancel</el-button>
        <el-button type="danger" @click="handleUploadFile">Confirm</el-button>
      </span>
    </el-dialog>
```

**JS :**

```
data(){ retrun ... }
methods:{
   beforeAvatarUpload(file) {
      this.objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file]));
      this.imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file]));
      const isJPG = file.type === "image/jpeg";
      const isPNG = file.type === "image/png";
      const isPDF = file.type === "application/pdf";
      const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 20;
      switch (file.type) {
        case "image/png":
          this.fileType = 1;
          break;
        case "image/jpeg":
          this.fileType = 2;
          break;
        case "application/pdf":
          this.fileType = 3;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      return isJPG && isPNG && isPDF && isLt2M;
    },
}
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?
Either offer me another way to re-write code.

If it needs more detailed information on my code, please let me know.

Comment: Do you want to show the preview of the PDF before it is being uploaded, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated. I finally found out the solution to my question.
I just use the `<embed>` tag to reach the preview function.

Here is my code :

```
<input @change="handleChange" />

// preview area
<embed
    v-if="embedSrc"
    type="video/webm"
    :src="embedSrc"
    width="100%"
    style="max-height: 50rem; min-height: 20rem"
/>

...
data:{
  return {
    embedSrc: ''
  }
}
...
methods:{
   handleChange(){
      this.embedSrc = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
   }
}
```

Please note that add `:` before src, either it can't get dynamic src correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing the `&&` to `||` ?

```
return isJPG || isPNG || isPDF || isLt2M;
```

or should I say,

```
return ( isJPG || isPNG || isPDF ) && isLt2M;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply firstly. 
but my question is not what you mentioned portion.

In my code that wrote ```this.imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file]));````
that's my confused parts, why imageUrl can't same as objectURL to show up the diagram berofe upload file to Amazon S3.

you can refer to the diagram with the link in my question to see the real situation

Wish you can help me to solve it.